# Practicing implementing a stack, need help understanding a strange behavior

Tags: java, stack

I am practicing implementing a stack in java for my compsci class, here is what I have:

```
public class Stack {
    private static Node head;

    private static class Node {
        private int value;
        private Node previous;

        Node(int i) {
        value = i;
        previous = null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        head = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Node n = new Node(i);
            n.previous = head;
            head = n;
        }
//        System.out.print(peek());
        System.out.print(pop().value);
        System.out.println();
        printValues(head);
    }

    private static void printValues(Node n) {
        while (n != null) {
            System.out.print(n.value + " ");
            n = n.previous;
        }
    }

    public static Node pop() {
        Node temp = head;
        temp.previous = null;
        head = head.previous;
//        temp.previous = null;
        return temp;
    }

    public static int peek() {
        return head.value;
    }
...
}
```

My issue is with the pop() method. The way it's currently written, when the main runs, only a 9 is printed to the console, and the printValues method produces nothing. But if I change the pop() method to:

```
    public static Node pop() {
        Node temp = head;
//        temp.previous = null;
        head = head.previous;
        temp.previous = null;
        return temp;
    }
```

Now the main works fully, and the console prints a 9, println() and then 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0.

What exactly is being affected by the placement of temp.previous = null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first one you're setting your `head` variable to null.

```
  Node temp = head;
  temp.previous = null;
  head = head.previous;
```

See? When temp is referencing the same Node as head is referencing, you set its previous to null, then you set the head to its previous (which you just set to null).

In the second one you're setting your `head` variable to the prior head's previous, which is your intention - and *then* disconnecting the prior head from the remainder of the stack.

```
  Node temp = head;
  head = head.previous;
  temp.previous = null;
```

Comment: So despite temp being a copy of head, it will still affect head? I'll have to wrap my head around this.

Comment: temp isn't a copy of head. It is a reference to the same object.

Comment: Okay, that clarifies it.